# MIME media type application/xml was not found Occurs only in production and not in local

Tags: xml, mime-types

I use Spring Boot Java.

Below exception occurs:

```
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class com.linkscreens.commons.exception.entity.MessageEntity, and Java type class com.linkscreens.commons.exception.entity.MessageEntity, and MIME media type application/xml was not found.
```

Below is the Java class

```
public class MessageEntity {

    private String code;
    private String description;

    public MessageEntity(String code, String description) {
        super();
        this.code = code;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }


}
```

The above issue only occurs in production and in local the code gets executed successfully without any exception.

Comment: You are missing a message writer.  See : https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/